# Flexor/extensor group in lower arm and limb bud rotation

Tags: human-anatomy, embryology

Have the flexor and extensor groups in the lower arm have rotated laterally 90° towards the humerus epicondyles independently of the rest of the lower arm? The pre-axial and post-axial veins are still in aligned with their segments in the upper arm, so I assume that the muscle mass that forms the flexor group was initially located on the anterior side aligned with the flexors in the upper arm. The other option is the entire lower arm rotating relative to the upper arm but it seems less likely.